# How to avoid necessity of writable .vbg in Visual Studio 6?

Tags: version-control, vb6, ide

I have a Project Group in Visual Studio 6 (`.vbg`). The projects are under source control (TFS). When I start debugging Visual studio there is an error `Path/file access error: Path/name.vbg` and dialog for "*Save Project Group As*" follows when canceled debugging runs without problems. To circumvent this annoyance I need to have the group file checked out or mark as readable just by file attribute. **Is there a way how to avoid this behavior?**

Notes: Situation was the same when Visual Source Safe was used. By my observation .vbg is not changed when the change is allowed. The problem can be connected with using English Windows with non English regional settings.

Comment: The Visual Basic IDE requires some files (`.vbp` files too) to be writeable, or at least it prompts to save them even if no changes have been made. I don't know of any way aroung this. Personally, I don't include my solution or VB group files in source control.

Comment: @Deanna: I don't have a problem with projects (at least usually). The group is processed by several developers.  Not to have .vbg in source control would complicated maybe even dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

No. Just keep the VBG in version control, and make the files read-write in your local directory.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be for you to save your VBG files to a folder outside of source control. It won't make a difference to the running directory - that is based on the EXE project (if any).

Comment: To force every developer to create group manually and edit it always when a project is added or removed is at least annoying if not even dangerous.

Comment: Yeah, but how often are Projects added and removed?  It's not that common.  I've never had a group with more than 12 projects in it...not that hard to manage